# Cómo hacer para que no se presionen varios botones a la vez en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, botón, vistas

El problema radica en que estoy haciendo un juego para 4 jugadores en el que no se pueden oprimir los botones a la vez, es decir hay cuatro botones en pantalla y cuando pase algo...(ej: una palabra clave) el mas rápido deberá oprimir un botón pero haciendo las pruebas el código no funciona como quisiera, alguna lógica que puede implementar?

```
public void runButton(View view) {
    //funcion llamada desde el activity en los botones
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p1) {
        p1++;
        lbl_p1.setText("" + p1);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p2) {
        p2++;
        lbl_p2.setText("" + p2);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p3) {
        p3++;
        lbl_p3.setText("" + p3);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p4) {
        p4++;
        lbl_p4.setText("" + p4);
    }
}//evento click de los botones
```

Comment: la forma que veo es agarrar el evento onclick de cada boton y en cada evento bloquear los otros 3 botones

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero como opción que al un usuario dar clic en un botón no permitas la interacción de los botones.

```
private boolean botonDeshabilitado = false;

...
...

public void runButton(View view) {

  //Si se dio clic anteriormente no se permite alguna operación
  if(botonDeshabilitado){ 
   return;
  }

    //funcion llamada desde el activity en los botones
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p1) {
        p1++;
        lbl_p1.setText("" + p1);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p2) {
        p2++;
        lbl_p2.setText("" + p2);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p3) {
        p3++;
        lbl_p3.setText("" + p3);
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_p4) {
        p4++;
        lbl_p4.setText("" + p4);
    }

     botonDeshabilitado = true; //deshabilita botones.

}//evento click de los botones
```

y llama otro método donde puedas habilitar que los botones puedan realizar nuevamente alguna acción.

```
private void habilitaNuevamente(){
   botonDeshabilitado = false;
}
```